# Unable to setup mongoDB MMS automation agent

Tags: mongodb-mms

I have installed automation agent on Ubuntu. but I am not sure about the next step to connect mms to that agent. could you please help me in this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps found at this blog http://blog.mms.mongodb.com/post/111860709590/introduction-to-import-existing-deployment-for and found that once the automation agent was successfully installed it connected to MMS and showed up correctly.  Do you have a firewall blocking any communication out from the server?